# replace the text of an element inside a variable in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a div

```
<div class='text'>
    <span class='s'>Some text</span>
</div>
```

```js
var div = $('.text');
```

Now I want to change the text of the span.
What I tried is

```
var span = $(div).find('span.s')[0];
$(span).text('some other text');
```

But I don't have any idea How to change this inside the `var div`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic isn't quite right. You just need to call `find()` on your original `div` variable, then set the `text()`. Try this:

```
var $div = $('.text');
var $span = $div.find('span.s');
$span.text('some other text');
```

Or more simply:

```
$('.text').find('span.s').text('some other text');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for simple text

```
$('.s').text('some other text');
```

Or this for HTML text

```
$('.s').HTML('some <strong>other</strong> text');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also execute your same task in one line of Jquery Code

```
$('div.text span.s:eq(0)).text('whatever the text you want');
```